# connection string in cookies asp.net

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I want to store connection string in cookies. But only server part is visible when i retrieve connection string from cookies. Can i store connection string in cookies? Based on company and unit i want to access database connection string and store it in cookies. so that for specific company there is specific connectionstring.
Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Do **NOT** store any sensitive information (such as connection strings) in Cookies!

You are asking to be hacked...

[Note: The fact that you think you need different connection strings for "each company and unit" would indicate a separate database for each; perhaps not the ideal way to go...]

Comment: My application is running on Lan only. There is no chance of security breach.

Comment: where should i store connection string so that for particular company there is a particulare connection string.

Comment: @Mohan Don't be foolish - that's flawed in two senses, firstly the assumption that all risks are external to your business and second that the app will remain within the lan. You *really* don't want to do this.

Comment: @Murph Where Should i store connection string?

Comment: First of all, I am not sure why you would want a separate database for each client - it makes more sense to use the relational nature of the database to separate individual user data. However, if you end up doing it that way I would suggest using ASP.NET profiles. Profiles are based on cookies, but the sensitive information would be stored in the database, not in a cookie.